# How to select a column IF

Tags: excel

I need to select another column if conditions are true.

```
Data 1            Data 2         Data 3
Buy Present       For Parents    Shopping Mall
Replace Light     For Parents    Home
Buy Groceries     For Parents    Shopping Mall
```

How to select Data 1 of the correct row dynamically?

```
=IF(AND(IFCOUNT(B:B, "For Parents") > 0, IFCOUNT(C:C, "Home")), xxxxx)
```

Comment: Is the expected result of the function "Replace Light"?

Comment: @BigBen Yes, it is.

Comment: If `Buy Present` is in `A2`, then try this: `=INDEX(A2:A4,SUMPRODUCT(MATCH(1,(B2:B4="For Parents")*(C2:C4="Home"),0)))`

Comment: that should be posted as a good answer.. ( :